# Measuring area of clipped data using shapefile in google earth engine: FIRECCI_5.1 Burned Area Product 500m

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, modis, calculate-values

I am trying to calculate burned area within the given shapefile from Modis burned area product in google earth engine. But I think I am getting wrong area as it is sometimes more than the area of shape file. Please check [my code here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/monishD/Burned_area_2019)

```
var admin2 = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level1");
var MP = admin2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Madhya Pradesh'));
var geometry = MP.geometry();
var rgbVis = {min: 0.0, max: 3000, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
var MPArea = geometry.area(1);
print('MPArea (m^2)', MPArea);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1').filterDate('2019-03-01','2019-05-31');
var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate');
var burned = burnedArea.mosaic().clip(MP)
// var burnedAreaB = burnedArea.clip(geometry)
// Use a circular palette to assign colors to date of first detection
var baVis = {min: 1,  max: 366,palette: [ 'ff0000', 'fd4100', 'fb8200', 'f9c400', 'f2ff00', 'b6ff05', '7787f9', '8b211c', '088712', '21f5ff', 'df2fff', '080fff']};
// var maxBA = burnedArea.max();
print(burned)
Map.centerObject(MP, 6.5);
Map.addLayer(burned, baVis, 'Burned Area');
var burnedA = burned.select('BurnDate');
var burnedImage = burnedA.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
var stats = burnedImage.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: MP,
 scale: 500, maxPixels: 10e13,//tileScale: 4});
print('pixels representing MODIS burned area: ', stats.get('BurnDate'), 'square meters');
```

what exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't go through your code in detail, but this is not what you want to do:

```
var burnedA = burned.select('BurnDate')
var burnedImage = burnedA.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
var stats = burnedImage.reduceRegion(...)
```

You multiply the burn date with the pixel area, and summing up these pixel values. That explains why your values are too big. You probably want to something like this instead:

```
var pixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(burnedA.mask())
var stats = pixelArea.reduceRegion(...)
```